# Counterexample about non Hausdorff topological vector spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I have some troubles with Hausdorffness in TVS:

Question 1. Is there any topological vector space $X$ which is not Hausdorff?

Question 2. Give an explicit example of a topological vector space $X$ (Hausdorff / non Hausdorff) such that $(X, \tau_w)$ is not Hausdorff?

Question 3. Prove that, for any topological vector space $X$, $(X^*, \tau_{w^*})$ always Hausdorff.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can equip any vector space with indiscrete topology (only $∅$ and $X$ are open) to get a topological vector space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q1. As mentioned in the comment, the indiscrete topology does the job.

Q2. Do you know a topological vector space $X$, where the dual space is just $\{0\}$? Then $\tau_w$ on this vector space $X$ is indiscrete.

Q3. Assume a non-zero element $x^*\in X^*$, i.e. $x^*(x)=c\neq 0$ for some $x\in X$. How can you seperate $x^*$ and $0$ by weak-star-neighbourhoods?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. In Q2, did you mean $\ell^p, \ 0<p<1$.
For Q3: Take $$V_1=V(0, x, \frac{|c|}{3})=\{y^*\in X^*: \ |y^*(x)|< \frac{|c|}{3}\},$$ and  $$V_2=V(x^*, x, \frac{|c|}{3})=\{y^*\in X^*: \ |(y^*-x^*)(x)|< \frac{|c|}{3}\}.$$ Then  $0\in V_1$, $x^*\in V_2$ and $V_1\cap V_2=\emptyset.$ 
Is that right.

Comment: Precisely. Good.

Comment: So why does Rudin say that all topological vector spaces are Hausdorff?

Comment: Answering my own comment: it's because Rudin assumes that all singletons are closed sets