# Statement on a neighborhood of $0$ in topological vector spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Consider a topological vector space $E$ and let $U\subseteq E$ be a neighborhood of $0$. I want to understand the proof of the following statement:

If $K\subseteq E$ is compact and $U$ is open with $K\subseteq U$, then there exists an open $W\subseteq E$ with $0\in W$, such that $K+W\subseteq U$.

The author of the book starts the proof as follows:

For every $x\in K$, one can pick $V$ a neighborhood of $0$ , such that $x+V\subseteq U$.

Unfortunately, I do not understand this step. Of course, since $U$ is a neighborhood of $0$, I can find an open set, which contains $0$ and translating this by $x$ would be a neighborhood of $x$, since the translation is an open map. However, I do not understand, why this should still be contained in $U$.

I have basically the following question: How can I guarantee, that the set $V$ is 'small' enough, such that $x+V$ is still contained in $U$?

Besides that, I want to mention that the statement above is only one bullet point of a Lemma. Only for this statement, the author requires, that $U$ should be open. Maybe it has to do with the openness of $U$?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can think of this as continuity of $y\mapsto x+y$ at $y = 0$. Recall that a map $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if for every $x\in X$ and $f(x)\in U$ we can find neighbourhood $V\subseteq X$ of $x$ with $f[V]\subseteq U$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows by the fact that $U$ is open and continuity of translation. Consider $x\in K\subset U$. Because $U$ is open there exists an open $x\in V'\subset U$. Now $V:=V'-x$ is an open containing $0$ by continuity of translation and has the property that $V+x\subset U$.

Comment: Oh, you mean, I could possibly just take $V:=U-x$? Because $V$ is open and $0\in V$, so it is a neighborhood of $0$. Then $x+V\subseteq U$, since $x+V=U$?

Comment: Ah yes I suppose you can choose $V=U-x$. I am not sure how the proof proceeds, but I suppose you will then take some finite intersections of opens with some nice properties because of compactness of $K$.

Answer (score 2):

In regards to your question

> I have basically the following question: How can I guarantee, that the set V is 'small' enough, such that x+V is still contained in U?

Every topological vector space is regular. See: [Every Topological Vector Space is Regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2332760/every-topological-vector-space-is-regular)

This means that you can always separate points and closed sets. In particular consider the closed set $C=E\setminus U$ and the point $x$, by this property you can find $W_1$ an open neighbourhood of $x$ and $W_2$ an open neighbourhood of $C$ that are disjoint.  The fact that they are disjoint implies that $W_1\subset U$.

This choice also implies that considering $$V=(W_1 - x)\cap U$$ we find that $V$ is a neighborhood of 0 and $V \subset U$. Furthermore

$$x+V \subset W_1 \subset U$$

Comment: That's interesting. Actually from your answer, I realise, that for any open $W\subseteq U$ with $0\in W$, one can choose $V=((W+x)\cap U)-x$ as open neighborhood of $0$, such that $x+V\subseteq U$. Thank you!